# How to start a cron task?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, cron

It sounds really simple, but many times I was stuck at the beginning of learning a new command. The tutorial writer think it's natural to start, but it's not.

This is the tutorial I've been reading:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

After reading that, I started something like:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/sh t.sh
```

And I got this error:

```
bxg: command not found
```

bxg is an empty file I created on the directory to debug, the tree graph is like this:

```
.
├── bxg
└── t.sh
```

Inside t.sh, the content is:

```
a=$(date)
mkdir "$a"
```

Obviously, bash didn't recognize this as a cron command.

Then I searched the cron process to see if it is started alread:

```
ps aux | grep cron

root       942  0.0  0.0   3056   908 ?        Ss   10:34   0:00 cron
zen       4924  0.0  0.0   4652   568 pts/1    T    11:54   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
zen       9722  0.0  0.0   4656   568 pts/1    S+   12:05   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Seems it's running there, but as another tutorial says that the process is called crond.
I tried the followed:

```
 service crond start
 crond: unrecognized service
```

Maybe the process I greped out with "ps aux" isn't the authentic process:

```
service cron start
start: Job is already running: cron
```

OK, I totally got no ideas now, friends help me!

Comment: You use bxg command in `t.sh`?

Comment: @Gnouc, nope, I've updated the question, bxg is just an empty file with arbitrary name

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `t.sh`

Comment: @Warwick， updated to the question already.

Comment: What do you want t.sh to do? It isn't entirely clear to me. Do you want to make a directory with today's date? You also mention `bash`, but your cron job uses `/usr/bin/sh` which is not the same as `bash`. `/usr/bin/sh` is the Bourne Shell. `bash` is the Bourne Again Shell which is a superset of the Bourne Shell. If you want `t.sh` to run in the `bash` shell, then change your cron entry from `* * * * * /usr/bin/sh t.sh` to `* * * * * /usr/bin/bash t.sh`

Comment: Are you typing `* * * * * /usr/bin/sh t.sh` to your shell? It should be put in your crontab file, which is done by running `crontab -e`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes I execute them in command line. The tutorial didn't mention that, or maybe  I missed it. Thank you, I'll try it

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, it seems that on my bash version I should crontab that file directly without -e flag.

Comment: There are a few ways to use the crontab command. Type `man crontab` to see how it can be used on your particular system.

Comment: @Warwick, what I do is using a toy sample to run a cron task. I know bash and sh are two different things. What's their difference in this case, will they produce different results? By the way, which directory will these datetime directories been put in? Since I didn't mention an absolute path in it.

Comment: @Mark - Nice diagnosis. I didn't think of that. Entering `*....` on the command line would try and run `bxg` which unless the `CWD` was in the user's `PATH` would give the error message `bxg: command not found`. Excellent work.

Comment: I believe that syntactically, Any `sh` script can be run unmodified by `bash`. However, the reverse is not true. If you run `/usr/bin/sh t.sh` on the command line, does it run without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crontab -e`

it will open a configuration file in editor and you then add your line to the end:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/sh t.sh`